# Query between Hibernate and Non-Hibernate Table

Tags: java, hibernate

Can we query using hibernate between Hibernate table and non-hibernate table?
Means one table is created using hibernate annotations i.e. domain object and other table is created manually in ms sql server 2008.

When I am trying It is giving Exception :-

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Invalid object name 'xyz.abc'
```

Comment: Yes,U can use hibernate for both hqlQuery and sqlQuery

Comment: String queryString = "Select name from Table1 m join xyz.abc c ON "+ obj.getID() +"= c.id";
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
List name = query.list();

How to do this ?

Comment: xyz.abc is it any column name

Comment: Here xyz is database name and abc is table name

Comment: Is two tables are in same database

Comment: No, both are in different database.

Comment: I have put into same database but still getting Exception
 :- ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Invalid object name 'abc'.

Comment: Both tables are containing entities

Answer (score 2):

No you cant query unmapped entities using HQL.You can query unmapped entities using SQL with help of `createSQLQuery` method.
Not sure if there is anyway to use sql + hql in same query.